# create a list ordered by a queryset

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
 def appelli(request, corso_id):
        corsi = Corso.objects.filter( pk=corso_id)
        fasca = Corso.objects.get( pk=corso_id)

      appello=[
        list(Iscrizione.objects.filter(corso1_id=fasca)),
         ...]

        return render(request, 'corsi/appello.html', {'appello':appello})
```

in the html use `{{appello.0}}`

and I render this:

> `[<Iscrizione: VFEW>, <Iscrizione: VFFF>]`

how can delete "Iscrizioni" and make a ordinate list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Iscrizione.objects.filter(corso1_id=fasca).values_list('fieldname', flat=True)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: yes, but in this case I render only the id.  list(Iscrizione.objects.filter(corso1_id=fasca).values_list('user', flat=True)),

Comment: You wanted to use {{appello.0}}, right? Then this is the correct answer for you.

Comment: .values_list('user__username', flat=True) use underline underline

Answer (score 0):

```
def appelli(request, corso_id):
    ...
    fasca = Corso.objects.get( pk=corso_id)
    appello= Iscrizione.objects.filter(corso1_id=fasca)

    context={
    'appello':list(appello),
     }

    return render(request, 'corsi/appello.html', context)
```

in the template you can use appello as an ordinary list.